# SQL Code to get Week Number when week begins Sunday to Saturday

Tags: mysql, sql

My company’s week begins on a Sunday.
The issue I’m having is extracting the week number from the date in the database.

For example,02/01/2022 falls in week 52 of 2021 using the Sunday week beginning logic. How can I write a SQL code to give me :

a) the week number (I.e 2nd Jan 2022 is part of week 52)

b) the correct year of the week. i.e 2nd Jan 2022 , I want it to bring back the year “2021” so my data set is complete and accurate.

N.b.
Database name I’m using is dw-fin and column of the date is called date-created

Comment: Please share any code that you might have tried so far.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the WEEK() function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WEEK](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php) function with a 'mode'.
Which is an integer indicating the starting of the week.
And the [YEARWEEK](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/yearweek-function-in-mysql/) function also has a mode.

| Mode | First day of week | Range | Week 1 is the first week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Sunday | 0-53 | with a Sunday in this year |
| 1 | Monday | 0-53 | with 4 or more days this year |
| 2 | Sunday | 1-53 | with a Sunday in this year |
| 3 | Monday | 1-53 | with 4 or more days this year |
| 4 | Sunday | 0-53 | with 4 or more days this year |
| 5 | Monday | 0-53 | with a Monday in this year |
| 6 | Sunday | 1-53 | with 4 or more days this year |
| 7 | Monday | 1-53 | with a Monday in this year |

Example :

> ```
> select date_column
> , month(date_column) as month
> , year(date_column) as year
> , yearweek(date_column, 2) as mode2_yearweek
> , floor(yearweek(date_column, 2)/100) as mode2_year
> , week(date_column, 2) as mode2_week
> from (select date('2022-01-01') as date_column) q;
> ```

| date_column | month | year | mode2_yearweek | mode2_year | mode2_week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 2022 | 202152 | 2021 | 52 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6e6aca941acaca9899649105a38dd29)*